# How to set card height depending on the height of the card with the largest height in the rows

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `row` like:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 1</h3>
                <p class="card-text">5 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 2</h3>
                <p class="card-text">3 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 3</h3>
                <p class="card-text">4 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, I have three cards with different heights (first 5 line, second 3 line, third 4 line) which is not much pretty...

I want these cards to have same height equal to the largest height (in this example 5 line).

Comment: You can use card decks for this - see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-decks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities to solve this.

**Add the [`h-100` utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent) to the card containers (`.card`):**

By using the `h-100` utility class the cards get the height of the columns. Since the columns are all the same height in one row, the cards get also all the same height.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Title 1</h3>
        <p class="card-text">
          5 Line Text<br>
          5 Line Text<br>
          5 Line Text<br>
          5 Line Text<br>
          5 Line Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Title 2</h3>
        <p class="card-text">
          3 Line Text<br>
          3 Line Text<br>
          3 Line Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Title 3</h3>
        <p class="card-text">
          4 Line Text<br>
          4 Line Text<br>
          4 Line Text<br>
          4 Line Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use [card decks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-decks) to make all cards the same height:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Title 1</h3>
          <p class="card-text">
            5 Line Text<br>
            5 Line Text<br>
            5 Line Text<br>
            5 Line Text<br>
            5 Line Text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Title 2</h3>
          <p class="card-text">
            3 Line Text<br>
            3 Line Text<br>
            3 Line Text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Title 3</h3>
          <p class="card-text">
            4 Line Text<br>
            4 Line Text<br>
            4 Line Text<br>
            4 Line Text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use and the **easiest** way to solve this issue is that use `h-100` class.

Just add [h-100](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) class and apply it on your `.card` div to make sure all `cards` have same height equal to the `largest` height card in your HTML.

**Live Working Demo:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 1</h3>
                <p class="card-text">5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text5 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 2</h3>
                <p class="card-text">3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text3 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title 3</h3>
                <p class="card-text">4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text4 Line Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```